# What do the colors mean in Pycharm console Window?

Tags: colors, console, pycharm

Some are apparent from context: blue is the IDE, black is stdout, and brown is stderr. But what is green? My program is displaying a cryptic green string before it quits ("quas"), and I have no idea where to look for the cause.